# AWS Athena - How to change format of date string

Tags: sql, date, amazon-athena, presto

I have a two tables in a database in AWS Athena that I want to join.

I want to join them by several columns, one of them being date.

However in one data set the date string is encoded for single value months is encoded as

```
 "08/31/2018"
```

While the other would have it encoded as

```
 "8/31/2018"
```

Is there a way to make them the same format?

I am unsure if it is easier to add the extra 0 to strings which have lack the extra 0 or to concatenate strings which have the extra 0.

Based on what I have researched I think I will have to use the CASE and CONCAT functions.

Both of the tables were loaded into the database from a CSV file, and the variables are in the string format.

I have tried changing the values manually in the CSV file, tried running an R script on one of the tables to format the date in the same way, and have also tried re-loading the tables into the database as the same date format.

However no matter what I do whenever it is loaded into the database, even when they have the same date type, it always loads them with different formats.

One with the the extra 0 and the other without it.

The last avenue I haven't tried is through a SQL query.

However I am not well versed in Athena and am having a hard time formatting this query.

I know this is rather vague, so please ask me for more information if you need.

If someone could help me start this query I would be grateful.

Thank you for the help.

Here is the query for changing dates in Athena.

```
  date_parse(table.date_variable,'%m/%d/%Y')
```

Though Athena tables are immutable once created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the value to date using `date_parse()`.  So, this should work:

```
date_parse(t1.datecol, '%m/%d/%Y') = str_to_date(t2.datecol, '%m/%d/%Y')
```

Having said that, you should fix the data model.  Store dates as *dates* not as *strings*!  Then you can use an equality join and that is just better all around.

Comment: In Presto the function is called `date_parse` https://prestosql.io/docs/0.172/functions/datetime.html#date_parse. I didn't check if `str_to_date` is available in Athena.